# How to reindex data frame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using `pandas` in Python, and I have performed some crosstab calculations and concatenations, and at the end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID        5    6    7    8     9    10   11   12    13
Total     87.0  3.0  9.0  6.0  92.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  20.0
Regular   72.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  81.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  18.0
CR        22.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  17.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   3.0
HDG       20.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0  4.0  0.0  0.0   1.0
PPG       30.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  40.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  14.0
Superior  15.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  11.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
CR         3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
HDG        5.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
PPG        7.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
```

The problem is that I want the last 4 rows, that start with `Superior` to be places before `Total` row. So, simply I want to switch the positions of last 4 rows with the 4 rows that start with `Regular`. How can I achieve this in `pandas`? So that I get this:

```
ID        5    6    7    8     9    10   11   12    13
Total     87.0  3.0  9.0  6.0  92.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  20.0
Superior  15.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  11.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
CR         3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
HDG        5.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
PPG        7.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
Regular   72.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  81.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  18.0
CR        22.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  17.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   3.0
HDG       20.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0  4.0  0.0  0.0   1.0
PPG       30.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  40.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  14.0
```

Comment: Do you want a generalized solution or one specific to this data set?

Comment: This sounds more like swapping rows rather than reindexing. There are lots of SO answers for that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import numpy as np
df.iloc[1:,:] = np.roll(df.iloc[1:,:].values, 4, axis=0)

       ID     5     6    7    8     9   10   11   12    13
0     Total  87.0  3.0  9.0  6.0  92.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  20.0
1  Superior  15.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  11.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
2        CR   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
3       HDG   5.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
4       PPG   7.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
5   Regular  72.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  81.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  18.0
6        CR  22.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  17.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   3.0
7       HDG  20.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0  4.0  0.0  0.0   1.0
8       PPG  30.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  40.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

More generalized solution `Categorical` and `argsort`, I know this df was ordered , so `ffill` is safe here

```
s=df.ID
s=s.where(s.isin(['Total','Regular','Superior'])).ffill()
s=pd.Categorical(s,['Total','Superior','Regular'],ordered=True)
df=df.iloc[np.argsort(s)]
df
Out[188]: 
         ID     5    6    7    8     9   10   11   12    13
0     Total  87.0  3.0  9.0  6.0  92.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  20.0
5  Superior  15.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  11.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
6        CR   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
7       HDG   5.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
8       PPG   7.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.0
1   Regular  72.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  81.0  7.0  3.0  3.0  18.0
2        CR  22.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  17.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   3.0
3       HDG  20.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0  4.0  0.0  0.0   1.0
4       PPG  30.0  2.0  8.0  5.0  40.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For a specific answer to this question, just use `iloc`

```
df.iloc[[0,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4],:]
```

For a more generalized solution,

```
m = (df.ID.eq('Superior') | df.ID.eq('Regular')).cumsum()
pd.concat([df[m==0], df[m==2], df[m==1]])
```

or

```
order = (2,1)
pd.concat([df[m==0], *[df[m==c] for c in order]])
```

where `order` defines the mapping from previous ordering to new ordering.